# Кодировка во Flask и значение None

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, flask

Всем привет. Простой вопрос, но не могу найти нигде ответ.

Написал функцию в отдельном модуле validation, которая обрабатывает входящий запрос и формирует словарь примерно такого вида:

```
{'error': False, 'data': 'Андрей, Жанна и ещё 2 человека лайкнули это', 'error_message': None}
```

Задача вывести при определенном запросе во flask такой результат:

{
"error": False,
"data": "Андрей, Жанна и ещё 2 человека лайкнули это",
"error_message": None
}

Для Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import validation

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/likes')
def get_likes():
    total = request.args.get('names')

    return validation.validation_names(total)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Возникло несколько проблем, которые не могу решить:

1. При выводе искажет русский язык, хотя в Pycharm работает идеально. получается типа:`\u0410\u043d\u0434\u0440\u0435\u0439, \u0416\u0430\u043d\u043d\u0430 \
2. При выводе значение словаря None преобразуется в null, можно конечно взять сделать строкой, но возможно как то иначе?
3. Можно ли как то вывести словарь не в одну строку а в несколько?`

Answer (score 1):

Если вы возвращаете `dict`, то Flask [по умолчанию](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/quickstart/#apis-with-json) преобразует ответ в JSON:

> If you return a dict from a view, it will be converted to a JSON response.

1. Cпецификация JSON допускает экранирование символов юникода. В вашем примере русский язык никак не искажён, только *закодирован*:

   ```json
   // Андрей, Жанна
   \u0410\u043d\u0434\u0440\u0435\u0439, \u0416\u0430\u043d\u043d\u0430
   ```
2. Объекта `None` в спецификации JSON нет. На этапе преобразования он заменяется аналогичным по смыслу `null`
3. Вы можете вручную преобразовать ответ в JSON, используя функцию [`flask.json.dumps`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.json.dumps), которая принимает аргумент `indent`:

   ```py
   return json.dumps(validation.validation_names(total), indent=4)
   ```

---

Если вы не хотите возвращать JSON, то можете преобразовать словарь в строку:

```py
return str(validation.validation_names(total))
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, с преобразованием в строку работает, но ваш ответ по пункту 3 почему то не сработатл.

Comment: @pauk97 Действительно. Исправил ответ